# UnificationEngine: Unable to send Requests via Python using TLS or SSL

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, unificationengine

I am attempting to use a Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B) to send Requests by Python to the Unification Engine. With SSL/TLS verification disabled, the request happens normally, but I need to get SSL/TLS working with it.

The below code is meant to force a session to use TLSv1 for the purpose of sending Python Requests to UnificationEngine:

```
class ForceTLSV1Adapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connection, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connection,maxsize=maxsize,block=block,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

def proxy_manager_for(self, proxy, **proxy_kwargs):
    proxy_kwargs['ssl_version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
    return super(ForceTLVS1Adapter, self).proxy_manager_for(proxy, **proxy_kwargs)

----Some Code here----

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://apiv2.unificationengine.com', ForceTLSV1Adapter())

----Some Code Here----
```

However, this error pops up after I send the request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 516, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 304, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 724, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 237, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 123, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 364, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 804, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 362, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 543, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/HumidityRequest.py", line 134, in <module>
    sendEmail(round(temp,3))
  File "/home/pi/Documents/HumidityRequest.py", line 92, in sendEmail
    r = requests.post('https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send', auth=(key,secret),data=userMessage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 420, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

I'm not sure what is the issue right now.

Comment: Does the server support tlsv1?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the certificate verification isn't done correctly.
Have a look at:
https://the.randomengineer.com/2014/01/29/using-ssl-wrap_socket-for-secure-sockets-in-python/
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl

you could also try the httplib.